# Why is it that protons and electrons have exactly the same but opposite charge?

Tags: electrons, particle-physics, protons, charge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do electron and proton have the same but opposite electric charge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21753/why-do-electron-and-proton-have-the-same-but-opposite-electric-charge)

Doesn't it seem very curious that one is an elementary particle and the other a subatomic particle yet the charge is exact same..

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21753/2451