# What is $Q_p/Q_e$ experimentally?

Tags: experimental-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

What is the experimental value of the ratio between the proton and the electron charge? Or more generally, is there a table that lists the ratio of the different nuclei charges to that of the electron?

Comment: Have you looked in the *Review of Particle Physics*? That is always the first place to check for these kinds of things.

Comment: Theoretical analogue: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21753/2451

Comment: Sry, on phone that's why brief. Yes I looked there quickly and there they quoted something like $(q_p+q_e)/e$ without defining these quantities, (or I missed them)

Comment: Duplicate? http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55513/

Comment: @dmckee: looks pretty close, though this seems to be more of the ratio than the sum (simple algebra swap though).

Comment: I'm with @dmckee - but for simple math, this is the same question.

Answer (score 3):

> [PDG] quoted something like $(q_p+q_e)/e$ without defining these quantities,

That is exactly what you asked for. Recall that the charge on the electron $q_e$ is negative and that on the proton $q_p$ is positive, so the *sum* there is exactly the difference in their magnitudes. Taking it as a fraction of the defined base charge $e$ makes it a dimensionless value that does not depend on units, and 
[$$ \frac{\left| q_p + q_e\right|}{e} \le 1 \times 10^{-21}$$ is a pretty good measurement](http://pdg8.lbl.gov/rpp2014v1/pdgLive/Particle.action?node=S016).

Comment: So here both $q$'s are measured while $e$ is the reference charge? Why not divide by $q_e$?

Comment: No doubt because it complicates the uncertainty expression, and with the difference being valued at $10^{-21}$ or less it simply doesn't matter to the result.