# Dirac magnetic monopoles and quark fractional electric charge quantization

Tags: charge, quarks, discrete, magnetic-monopoles, dirac-monopole

When applying the Dirac quantization rule for electric and magnetic charge, I assume one is considering unit electric charges such as electrons.  How does the Dirac quantization rule apply for the fractional electric charges of quarks?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21753/2451

Comment: I answer this question at http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268709/.

Answer (score 4):

The Dirac quantization rule comes from integrating the angular momentum of the superposed electromagnetic field of a charge and a monopole. This angular momentum turns out to be finite and independent of the distance $h$ between the charge and the monopole. The argument then goes that if it's possible to isolate a single fundamental charge $e$ and a single fundamental monopole $g$ in some region of space, then the total angular momentum in that region has to be a multiple of $\hbar$. Here "isolation" means that the distance to any other particle is $\gg h$.

But note that the isolation of the particles is critical. If you put a monopole near a hydrogen atom, the total angular momentum of the electromagnetic field vanishes, because the angular momentum density is of the form $\textbf{E}\times\textbf{B}$, which is bilinear in the fields.

Since quarks are confined, the argument can never be applied to a quark.

Comment: This is a good point.  Nonetheless, the argument does apply to QFTs where the number of flavors is high enough that confinement doesn't happen.

Comment: What if you raised the temperature above the [Hagedorn temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagedorn_temperature)?  Then quarks would deconfine, and you could transport a single quark around the Dirac string.

Comment: Your argument doesn't apply in the case where you move a quark around a monopole in a circle smaller than the confinement radius, or above the Hagedorn radius.  See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/268709/which-charge-to-use-in-the-dirac-quantization-condition for the complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

The logic is the same:  If $q$ is an electric charge and $g$ is a magnetic charge, one must have $gq \in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$ (in lazy theorist units).  So if there is a largest magnetic charge, then there is necessarily a smallest electric charge.  You don't have to assume that you are dealing with unit charges to make this argument.