# Charge of electrons and protons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrons, charge, protons

I have a question which reads:

> "A conductor has a charge of $9.6 * (10)^{-19}$ coulomb. The conductor will have- "

The problem I face in this question is due to not knowing the exact value of the charge of electrons. Is it $1.6 \cdot (-10)^{-19}$ or $-1.6 \cdot (-10)^{-19}$ or $1.6 \cdot (-10)^{19}$ ?

In fact, since, the $1.6$ remains constant, I divided $9.6$ by $1.6$ and got $6$. But the options ((a) 6 electron less (b) 6 electron more) are confusing.

I researched and found these things ([1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21769/what-is-the-reason-behind-specific-values-for-charge-of-electrons-protons), [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21753/why-do-electron-and-proton-have-the-same-but-opposite-electric-charge) and rest are marked duplicate) here but did not find the value of charge in them. .

Could you help me out?

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) has the information you need: $-1.6\times10^{-19}$ C; I presume your textbook also says the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) gives the electric charge as $-1.6\times10^{-19}$ Coulombs.