# Why does the electron charge have its specific value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrons

Why electron and other particles (proton and etc) have the same charge value $1.6021766208×10^{−19}\:\mathrm C$? Why they do not have different charge values?

Is it unresolved problem of physics or it is well known why?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant

Comment: The point is not the value, is the definition of the Coulomb ($1C=1A\cdot 1s$) and therefore of the Ampere: "the ampere is the constant current that will produce an attractive force of $2\times 10^{−7}$ newtons per metre of length between two straight, parallel conductors of infinite length and negligible circular cross section placed one metre apart in a vacuum." (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampere))

Comment: While they refer to $c$ instead of $e$, [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/127602/why-are-the-anthropometric-units-which-are-about-as-big-as-we-are-as-large-as) and its linked duplicates contain the essentials of the answer: the numeric value of dimensionful constants is meaningless, as it depends on the size of our units.

Comment: Also related: [What is the reason behind specific values for charge of electrons, protons?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21769), [The origin of the value of speed of light in vacuum](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3644), [Why does the speed of light cc have the value it does?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56973), and their many `Linked` relatives.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed my question. Why electron, proton and other particles have the same charge value? why they are not different?

Comment: That would make your question a duplicate of [Why do electron and proton have the same but opposite electric charge?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21753/why-do-electron-and-proton-have-the-same-but-opposite-electric-charge). If you wish to edit further, you do need to do a comprehensive search of this site to make sure it's not been asked before.