# What is the quantum of mass?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, discrete

Just like charge, other physical quantities such as energy, angular momentum and mass are also quantized. But what if mass is quantized? What is the quantum of mass?

Comment: Energy is not generically quantized.

Comment: @NiharKarve Is angular momentum not quantised in units of $\frac{\hbar}{2}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we have an elementary charge but no elementary mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4238/)