# What is the mass in $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}_g=\text{something}$ called if it could be non-zero?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gravity, magnetic-monopoles

1. Maxwell's equation for gravity has 
   $$\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}_g~=~0,$$ 
   see [Gravitoelectromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) in analogy with the electrodynamics. 
   What is the mass called that needs to make these equations symmetric in $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}_g=\text{something}$?
   There are no magnetic monopoles so far but the electric charge is quantized anyway.
2. My other question is: What is preventing the quantization of mass or is it considered quantized as built from elementary particles?

Comment: More on [gravitoelectromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=url%3a%22*.wikipedia.org%2fwiki%2fGravitoelectromagnetism%22).

Answer (score 1):

The last part of the question (v4) is a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122/2451) and [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4238/2451) Phys.SE questions and links therein. Here we will only address the first part of the question (v4).

The formalism of [gravitoelectromagnetism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitoelectromagnetism) (GEM) is traditionally$^1$ derived from a weak field limit

$$\tag{1} g_{\mu\nu}~=~\eta_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}, \qquad h_{\mu\nu}~\ll~ 1,$$

of General Relativity (GR), where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is a fixed background reference metric, usually taken to be the flat space Minkowski metric. Here the first row/column

$$\tag{2} h_{0\mu}~=~h_{\mu 0}~=~A_{\mu}$$

of the $h_{\mu\nu}$ tensor is identified with the GEM gauge $4$-potential $A_{\mu}$, see e.g. Ref. 1. The main point is that the GEM electric field $\vec{E}$, and the GEM magnetic field$\vec{B}$, i.e. the electric-magnetic field-strength $F_{\mu\nu}$, are defined from $A_{\mu}$ by standard formulas for [EM in a fixed curved space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime), which implement the GEM no-magnetic monopole Maxwell equation

$$\tag{3} \vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}~=~0 $$

manifestly via a Bianchi identity a la [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/71614/2451) Phys.SE answer. Here we have implicitly assumed that the background metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ doesn't have singularities. In other words, a GEM magnetic monopole in a regular spacetime point of the background metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ would violate the weak field framework that GEM traditionally is derived from. On the other hand, it seems that GEM magnetic monopoles may be associated with e.g. NUT-type singularities in $\eta_{\mu\nu}$, see Ref. 3.

References:

1. B. Mashhoon, *Gravitoelectromagnetism: A Brief Review,* [arXiv:gr-qc/0311030](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0311030).
2. R. Maartens and B.A. Bassett, *Gravito-electromagnetism*, [arXiv:gr-qc/9704059](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9704059).
3. D. Momeni, M. Nouri-Zonoz, and R. Ramazani-Arani, *Morgan-Morgan-NUT disk space via the Ehlers transformation,* [arXiv:gr-qc/0508036](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0508036).

--

$^1$ Ref. 2 claims to have developed a fully covariant GEM formalism with magnetic monopoles (hat tip: Michael Brown).

Comment: There is a [fully covariant (and as far as I can tell fully non-linear) version of GEM](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9704059), but what bearing this has on the question I don't know...

Comment: I updated the answer.