# I want to know about the quantization of mass

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, mass, discrete, binding-energy

Is mass quantized? If yes, then why do we see all amounts of mass? Well , can it be said quantized just for smaller masses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122/