# Why is (rest) mass not discrete?

Tags: mass, charge, discrete

We say charge is discrete because it always has the form $q = n e$, where $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Similarly, I can say that $m = n N_a \mu$, where $n$ is number of moles, $N_a$ is avogadro's constant and $\mu$ is the mass of one atom/molecule of that element. 
Since $nN_a$ is the number of atoms/molecules, it will not make sense to have $\pi$ atoms or $1.5$ atoms, so $nN_a$ is a natural number.

By this mass is clearly discrete like charge. However, my textbook says the following

> One of the main differences between charge and mass is that mass is continuous and charge is not.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4238/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @Qmechanic I searched for "quantized" before asking the question and this question did not come up. Even I was surprised that this question is not asked before.

Comment: [Is mass quantized?](https://www.quora.com/Is-mass-quantized)

Answer (score 1):

You can decompose an atom into its sub-particles and observe masses which are not integer multiples of, in your terminology, $\mu$. Even without decomposing, you can still change the mass of an atom by giving it energy in different forms like heat, which will increase its overall energy hence mass, à la $E=mc^2$. This is not the case for charge.

Comment: But charge can also be in fractions.

Comment: @A---B Only as small as $e/3$, of which charges are integer multiples, whereas masses are more like real numbers.

Comment: @J.G. But you can only divide mass to the level of protons, neutrons and electrons right ? and there is no half proton or 0.1 electron. So how mass is real number ?

Comment: @A---B It's partly because there isn't a neat ratio for those particles' masses (not to mention some others we won't get into), but the other issue is binding energy reduces slightly the total mass of a nucleus, atom or molecule because $E=mc^2$.

Comment: @J.G. I can't argue much because I don't know much. But the obvious conclusion is that mass was discrete before Einstein was born.

Comment: @A---B We might then have approximated an atom's mass in the form $Z(m_p+m_e)+Nm_n$.

Comment: @J.G. What is $Z$ and $N_{m_n}$ ?

Comment: @A---B $Z$ is proton number, $N$ is neutron number, $m_n$ is neutron mass.

Comment: @J.G. Then the mass would be discrete.