# Relation between quantisation of mass and Higgs field

Tags: mass, higgs, discrete

Mass is not quantised meaning that it doesn’t come in the form of integral multiples.

From my understanding mass is basically resistance to acceleration.
Higgs field gives mass to elementary particles. The particles that interact with the Higgs field more are more heavier than those that do not interact with the field much.

https://physics.aps.org/articles/v6/111

> The Higgs boson does not technically give other particles mass. More precisely, the particle is a quantized manifestation of a field (the Higgs field) that generates mass through its interaction with other particles.

Does this statement contradict the fact that mass cannot be quantised?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122/2451 and links therein.

Comment: You are conflating QFT "quantization" with the topological quantization arguments for charges and such.  The two words are applied in dramatically different contexts and are not related.

Comment: @CosmasZachos so does this mean that quantisation is defined differently for both cases in the above scenario ? Understood. I will research more.

Comment: Absolutely. The near duplicate question linked explains that adequately.