# Quantisation of mass

Tags: mass, discrete, elementary-particles

My textbook says:

> Quantisation of electric charge is a basic (unexplained) law of nature;
> interestingly, there is no analogous law on quantisation of mass.

Does this mean we can have arbitrarily small masses? In particular, can we have masses smaller than the electron?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino#Flavor,_mass,_and_their_mixing

Comment: The neutrinos seem to have masses smaller than that of the electron

Comment: Can we have masses smaller than the neutrino? If not, can't we define the mass of a neutrino as the basic unit of mass?

Comment: What is not clear about the statement that there is no quantization of mass, either experimentally or in mainstream theory?

Comment: @Ghoster What if I were to claim that every mass is an integer multiple of the mass of a neutrino? Could you prove me wrong?

Comment: Of course not. The neutrino masses haven’t been measured. It would be a claim without any experimental or theoretical justification, and it would be ignored.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "does it follow from non-quantization of mass that arbitrarily small masses are possible?" is no. If the lightest particle has rest mass $m>0$, then there is no system with a mass in $(0,m)$, but the mass spectrum would be continuous above a certain point, so mass wouldn't be quantized. For example, assuming there's no strong force like electromagnetism between the particles, the rest mass of a system of two of the particles would be roughly $2m\sqrt{(1+γ)/2}$ where $γ$ is the gamma factor of their relative speed, so any mass in $[2m,\infty)$ is possible. (That's a bit of a cheat, because the particles will fly apart unless you confine them in a box, which would also have mass. But by the strict definition of rest mass it's true.)

In reality, the lightest particle is not an electron or neutrino but a photon. A system of two or more photons can have any nonzero rest mass (with the same caveat as above).

Answer (score 1):

Your textbook's statement is correct. If you consider the case hypothetically, you can have infinitesimally small masses, but in practise, the smallest non-zero mass of a particle that has been measured is the electron mass, 511 keV. There is no limit to the size of a mass that can be measured.

*Note: One of the comments say that neutrinos seem to have masses smaller than that of electron which is absolutely correct but we have not measured it to a satisfactory extent.*

[***The KATRIN experiment recently released its latest result of the neutrino-mass measurement. The experiment established an upper limit of 0.8 eV/c2, or 1.4×10-33 grams. This is the most stringent laboratory limit of the neutrino mass from tritium beta-decay measurements. This limit highlights a remarkedly light neutrino mass, and future improvements with more data will allow scientists to better understand the evolution of our universe.***](https://www.energy.gov/science/np/articles/direct-neutrino-mass-measurement-achieves-new-sub-electronvolt-sensitivity#:%7E:text=Summary,from%20tritium%20beta%2Ddecay%20measurements.)

#### ***Hope this is helpful. Do correct me if I'm wrong!***